# Offset in glDrawElements using LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vao, index-buffer

I'm trying to render only some of the Indices stored in the index buffer of an VAO.

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

I know that the second parameter is the count of vertices to draw, in this case one triangle and the last parameter is the offset as a pointer. But how do I specify this pointer using LWJGL/Java?

Answer (score 1):

Oh. I just have to specify the offest in bytes. I use floats, so to start at the scond triangle I would have to set the last parameter to 3 * 4.